# ec2 commandline snapshot rename

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an automated script that runs ec2-create-image on my instances to have a highly available backup. When ec2-create-image is run it creates a snapshot with a blank "Name" field. Is there any way to change the "Name" field from the commandline?

I've looked at the man page for ec2-modify-snapshot-attribute, but this only seems to be able to modify permissions of a snapshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'Name' attribute of a snapshot is actually a tag. As such, you can change/set it with the `ec2tag` command line tool.

```
 ec2tag snap-xxxxxxxx -t Name=SNAP_NAME
```

As per the help file:

```
 SYNOPSIS
      ec2addtag ([ec2-create-tags, ec2tag])
      ec2addtag [GENERAL OPTIONS] RESOURCE_ID [RESOURCE_ID ...] --tag KEY[=VALUE] [--tag KEY[=VALUE] ...]   

 GENERAL NOTES
      Any command option/parameter may be passed a value of '-' to indicate
      that values for that option should be read from stdin.   

 DESCRIPTION
      Adds a set of tags to a set of resources. To update a tag's key or value, you also use CreateTags.
          The new values overwrite the old values.

 -t, --tag TAG
           Tag in the form of key[=value].
```

`ec2tag` is the 'shortform' of `ec2addtag` - they both do the same thing. They are included as part of the EC2 API tools.